# Loading css file in django allauth login page

Tags: python, html, css, django

I can't seem to be able to change the css of my allauth login page. I would like to add some custom css to change a few things.

I created a base.css file

```
div_id_login.form-group{
    font-weight:200;
}
```

That is loaded in my login.html file

```
{% extends "account/base.html" %}

{% load i18n %}
{% load account socialaccount %}
{%  load crispy_forms_tags %}
{%  load static %}

{% block head_title %}{% trans "Sign In" %}{% endblock %}
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
{% block content %}

<h1 style = "text-align: center;">{% trans "Sign In" %}</h1>
...
```

The div class mentioned in the base.css file should be this:

[image: login]

I have made changes to my base.html file according to the answer suggested:

```
{%  load static %}
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <head>
    <title>{% block head_title %}{% endblock %}</title>
    {% block extra_head %}
    {% endblock %}
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Vkoo8x4CGsO3+Hhxv8T/Q5PaXtkKtu6ug5TOeNV6gBiFeWPGFN9MuhOf23Q9Ifjh" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
  </head>
```

However, still the css changes I made are still not appearing in login.html

Answer (score 1):

Your login.html file extends account/base.html so you need to include this:

```
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="{% static 'css/base.css' %}">
</head>
```

inside a block that is defined in account/base.html.  Often there is an `extra_head` block or similar that you can use for the job.

Comment: I tried this, still not getting the css on the login page

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's because Django can't find your base.css. Do you get a 404 error when you access the CSS upon visiting the webpage? The error would appear like this in the console while running the server:

```
GET /static/account/style.css HTTP/1.1" 404 1677
```

In my case, my CSS file is located in `<project directory>/static/account/style.css`

Django can't seem to find my `style.css` so I added this in the project's `settings.py`:

```
STATICFILES_DIRS = [
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static"),
]
```

And the CSS file is working now. Django's static file searching is kind of tricky.